# How to set dark mode except for text?

Tags: screen, dark-mode

I like dark mode but the problem is that it is difficult to read text on a black background so that when I read in dark mode, my eyes become watery.
So, is there a way to exclude texts from darkmode, such that there is a white box behind texts..?

Comment: Not possible in general but a developer can make an app that way.

Comment: @Irfan Latif How can we do that? Can we edit an app to make it like this?//Thanks for replying